# body и html не растягивается до конца страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У html и body высота попросту меньше всей страницы с информацией (у меня background - фон прикреплен к низу Body,поэтому очень важно чтобы картинка была в конце страницы). Попробовал сменить height  на min-height (=100%) у body/html, и они прибавили в высоте, но до сих пор не достают до конца. Вычитал что проблема лечится , если прописать DOCTYPE html (у меня его вообще не было). Прописал, body не увеличился, но появился какой-то чертов shadow-root из-за которого некоторые стили отменились и теперь пол верстки коту под хвост. shadow-root появляется после html и только в браузере, не знаю как убрать его (пытался искать, но без результатов) и как растянуть body/html до конца. Буду рад любым советам, все перепроверю :(

Comment: эх, тянуть `body` а тем более `html` совершенно безсмысленное занятие, а вот потянуть `div` можно

Comment: @Dmitry, что? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy я к тому что лучше тянуть div, чем тянуть body ну а html вообще не для этого

Comment: @Dmitry, наоборот.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно подробнее? а то я как-то по старинке использую div в качестве контейнера с которым и играюсь

Comment: @Dmitry, мой ответ посмотри.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/af05a1cb13d41f0e2e8a4b0f2f5d889e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG) repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 body {
   background-position: center top;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% auto;
 }
```

А весь код хтмл код обверни в

```
<div class="wrapper">
твой код
</div>
```

и что-то в духе

```
.wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Теоретически должно сработать.
+Используй normalize.css или reset.css

Comment: Не должно и не будет.