# Как растянуть body и html на всю высоту браузера?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть такой глюк на странице, `html` и `body` не растягиваются на всю высоту браузера из-за этого все внутренние элементы выходят за ее пределы. Как это исправить?

Задал

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

не помогло.

Comment: `html, body {height: 100vh}`

Comment: Спасибо, но ваш совет не помог!

Comment: @fanfer лучше все же `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [body и html не растягивается до конца страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463187/body-%d0%b8-html-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: Не помогает не height: 100% ни min-height: 100vh

Comment: @Артур значит у вас есть еще что-то, что отменяет 100vh...

Comment: Андрей что это может быть?

Comment: @Артур например css-код для `body` ниже инструкции, в которой задается `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: Андрей вот код: html, body, .container {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 27px;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-300';
 color: #22241b;
}

Comment: @Артур если вы хотите, чтобы не только `body`, но и `.container` растягивался на всю высоту экран, дайте и контейнеру `100vh`. Когда вы даете высоту 100% это значит, что браузер высчитывает высоту контейнера на основе высот вложенных элементов.

Answer (score 3):

Все растягивается:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Вместе с содержимым `container` тоже на всю высоту:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background: orangered;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

А вот если Вы об этом, что вн. контент больше высоты экрана (высоты `body, html`):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.container {
  background: orangered;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Тогда либо убрать для `body, html` высоту в 100%, либо задавать минимальную высоту (`min-height: 100vh` или `min-height: 600px`).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.container {
  background: orangered;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Может проблема именно с последней секцией? Потому что до последней секции все тянется хорошо.

Comment: Мне кажется именно последняя секция не растягивается. Именно элементы выпадают с последней секции.

Comment: Может быть есть возможность весь код сюда выложить? Подозреваю что еще есть элементы с `float`  в данном случае стоит применить для всей обертки (`body') `overflow:hidden` или clearfix применять. Бывает теряется закрывающий тег и все тоже ломается. Ситуации разные бывают как и баги)

Comment: float у меня нет, я использую флексбокс, мне кажется это проблема именно с position, потому что когда я position убрал, все стало на свои места, но мне нужен все равно position, чтобы с позиционировать элемент по отношению к блоку, но только чтоб элементы не выпадали из своего потока

Comment: Теперь все растягивается как нужно, но теперь как мне с позиционировать элемент, чтоб все было как надо?

Comment: Хотя нет, я ошибся position тут не причем я правил элемент с помощью отрицательного маржина, поэтому секция не растягивается на всю высоту

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, я наконец-то решил эту проблему, я убрал отрицательный марджин, и добавил элементу position: relative с отрицательным значением, и все стало как надо, это походу глюк из-за отрицательного марджина был

Comment: отлично ........)

Answer (score 0):

Вот код без `min-height: 100vh`:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/*  min-height: 100vh; */
}
```

А вот код с ним:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не фиксируй высоту явно, всегда min-height задавай. А то если дочерние компоненты превысят высоту, начнут выпадать из контейнера.

Comment: Я и задаю всегда min-height

Comment: @Артур https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bmoRLo

Answer (score 0):

можно и так сделать, а содержимое уже высоту определит. Залей на гитхаб может, и ссылку дай

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю проблему. Для `html` не видел чтобы css задавали, он и без них нормально тянется. Для `body` зафиксировал высоту, и контейнеры выпадать стали.

У первого контейнера высота минимальная задана, поэтому он увеличивает высоту, так как второй контейнер превысил эту высоту.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html{
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
}
body{
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:yellow;
}
.container-1{
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background-color: blue;
}
.container-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height:  250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="container-2"></div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPEoZZ)